# Source has 3 element(s) but target allows only 1.ts(2322)

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to update this interface to allow for n Apps?

Interface file

```
export interface Apps {
    entry: object;
    content: {
        label: string;
        visible: boolean;
    };
    name: string;
    length: number;
}

export type AppsList = [Apps]
```

Unit test file below
appsArray complains of source having 3 elements but target allows only 1

```
const appsArray: AppsList = [
    {
        entry: {},
        content: {
            label: 'Search',
            visible: true,
        },
        name: 'search',
        length: 0,
    },
    {
        entry: {},
        content: {
            label: 'Management',
            visible: true,
        },
        name: 'mc',
        length: 0,
    },
    {
        entry: {},
        content: {
            label: 'Clones Internal Metrics',
            visible: false,
        },
        name: 'internal_metrics',
        length: 0,
    },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export type AppsList = Apps[];
```

Comment: Trying to get AppsList to extend Response but get the following error or warning. `Generic type 'AppsList' requires 1 type argument(s).ts(2314)` This is how i try to get it to extend. `export type AppsList<Response> = App[];`

Comment: If `AppsList` is not intended to be generic, then you'd use `type AppsList = App[];`  It looks like this is probably the case, since the generic parameter `Response` is not used anywhere.  If you want `AppsList` to actually *be* `Response` also, then you'd use `type AppsList = App[] & Response;`.

Comment: Following error occurs:
  Type 'App[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Response': headers, ok, redirected, status, and 11 more.ts(2345)

Comment: There's not enough information here to solve the problem.  Try to create the smallest example that illustrates the problem.  Post a question with the complete example code.  Anything other than that, and I'll just be guessing and wasting both our time.